# What is the meaning of "return ret < 0"?

Tags: c, return-value, ffprobe

Functions can return a number, pointer, and most of the type you want, but what's the meaning of it?

```
return ret < 0;
```

(This code snippet is from the last line of the code, [ffprobe.c](https://raw.github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/ffprobe.c).)

Comment: What part of that do you not understand?  Do you know the "return" keyword in C?  Do you know the comparison operator `<`?  Do you recognize `ret` as a variable declared earlier?  Put it all together....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will return either `1` or `0` depending upon the condition `ret < 0` is `true` or `false`.

You can understand this as

```
if(ret < 0)
    return 1;
else  
    return 0;
```

Comment: Aww edited to say half of what I said. At least it's more clear for the op.

Comment: Before your answer I already had edited my answer but I became late because of my slow internet connection (Downloading a game *Injustice* :D)

Comment: Just a friendly jibe. Just happy it's clear. The kind of traditional C coding style is confusing for people new to it who've probably seem more explicit coding styles (in normal human reading terms) while the traditional C pedantic people would say it is explicit because they are used to reading code the hard way by order of evaluation.

Comment: In other terms you can say: *Its a beauty of C* :)

Answer (score 2):

It returns the value of the conditional operation. 
`ret < 0`
It's C shorthand that you often see. 
C programmers are notoriously pedantic and do not write code that is obvious to the learner. 
It's equivalent to what might be written explicitly for mortals as

if ( ret < 0 ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}

Answer (score 1):

return statement can have a expression.
when a function is returning using a return statement it evaluates the expression first.

```
       return (expression);
```

expression can be any valid expression in C. after evaluation it returns whatever value is the output of the expression(assuming the return type matches or compiler will through an error )
in your case the statement will be like

```
      return (ret < 0);
```

depending on the value of ret either 1( if ret is less than 0)  or 0(if ret is greater than 0) will be returned